# Batch file that will only download new files from FTP?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the code below to download files from an FTP server. Is there some way in this that I can check for date modified or different file size and only download the new files?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=
Set _UserName=
Set _Password=
Set _LocalFolder= C:\Presentation\video
Set _Filename= /Presentation/video
Set _ScriptFile=ftp4

>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo Mget %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
msg * "Transfer Complete"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three options.

1 - Write code to handle it.

- Use a similar script to get the list of files with details (size, date) included
- Iterate this list against the existing files to determine which needs to be downloaded and in the process generate a script that downloads only the needed files
- Execute that script

Sorry, no included code for this option. I don't know anything about your ftp server, files names, date format, subfolders, ....

2 - Download all the files to a temporary directory and use robocopy to update the desired target directory

3 - Use a scriptable ftp client that allows you to do what you need.

Option 1 means more work, 2 means more traffic/time, 3 should be the best option IF it is allowed.